# Can't install git in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: git, ubuntu-16.04

I have recently dual booted my laptop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to install git by using `sudo apt-get install git` but I get this message-

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
git-man liberror-perl
Suggested packages:
git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk
gitweb git-arch git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn
The following NEW packages will be installed:
git git-man liberror-perl
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,624 kB of archives.
After this operation, 27.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 liberror-perl all 0.17024-1
Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 git-man all 1:2.9.3-1
Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 git amd64 1:2.9.3-1
Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libe/liberror-perl/liberror-perl_0.17024-1_all.deb  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/git-man_2.9.3-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/git_2.9.3-1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I am very much new to ubuntu. I am connected to a Lan connection and the internet is working fine (though I cannot connect to wifi on Ubuntu which I can't figure out why, but that's a problem for another day). I tried following various links and looking for a solution to my problem but in vain. Can anyone please guide me what to do about it?

Comment: Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

suggests there's some problem with the connection. to you have the internet working? are you behind some proxy/firewall rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I was using proxy so I needed to do proxy manual settings in network settings and then I needed to install the software updates.
Thank you people for your responses anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your the git files if there's any and run `apt-get install git-core` insted ;)